# Sorting hashmap in angularjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created form like this:

```
<form role="form">
         <div class="emailRow">
           <label ng-model="emailLbl" for="userEmailID">Email ID</label>
           <input type="text" ng-model="user.emailId" name="userEmailID"  id="userEmailID" placeholder="Enter your email ID" required />
                <div ng-if="getErrorMessage('emailId','1')">
                        {{getErrorMessage('emailId')}}</div>
    </div> 
    <br/>
    <div class="passwordRow">
           <label ng-model="passwordLbl" for="userPassword">Password</label>
           <input type="password" ng-model="user.password"  name="userPassword" id="userPassword" placeholder="Enter your password" required />
                    <div ng-if="getErrorMessage('password','2')">
                        {{getErrorMessage('password')}}</div>
    </div> 

        <br/>
         <div class="buttondRow">
        <button class="button loginBtn" ng-click="loginSubmit(user)">Show Login Form</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

I am validating emailId and password using server side validations and passing error list as response. Now, I want to display error messages at top in order of fields.
So, in getErrorMessage() method, I have passed fieldName along with field's sequence no.

and I have created hashmap as follows:

```
$scope.getErrorMessage = function(errorCode,sequenceNo) {
            for ( var i = 0; i < data.validationErrors.length; i++) {
            if(data.validationErrors[i].errorCode == errorCode){
                hashmap[sequenceNo] = data.validationErrors[i].errorDescription;
                return data.validationErrors[i].errorDescription;
            }
        }
    }
Now I want to sort this hashmap based on key which is my field sequence no
```

How should I do this in javascript or angualrjs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use array initially?

Comment: there is no guarantee on order of keys in a JS object. And why would you want to have keys called '0' and '1' in an object, use an array instead.

Comment: I don't get your use case. More context might help. And you can also just add items to array on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

bit roundabout...

```
function compare(a,b){
    if(+a && +b){
        return (+a) - (+b);
    }
  return a.localeCompare(b);
}

var hm={};
hm[1] = 55;
hm[3] = 13;
hm[12] = 22;

var keys = Object.keys(hm);
keys.sort(compare);
for(var i in keys){
    console.log(keys[i], hm[keys[i]]);  // or something else that you might want to do with the details
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand why you are calling/naming it as hashmap, while it is seems to be a plain array of string as:

```
a[1] = "please enter...."
a[2] = "please enter...."
:
:
```

In javascript/angular you can define your array as:

```
var arr = [] ; // note here... not curly braces
```

then you can call javascript function sort() as

```
arr.sort();
```

Otherwise your can use simple javascript for loop or angular.forEach() loop to do your job.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this using lodash:

```
var hashmap={};
var array;

hashmap[2] = "Please enter password"; 
hashmap[1] = "Please enter emailId";
hashmap[3] = "Please enter name";

_.sortBy(hashmap, function(n) {
  array = hashmap;
});

console.log(array);
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/288/

Comment: 1. Your function must return something 2. `array` is identical to `hashmap` - you simply assigned it.